# Complete and minimally sufficient example for monitoring events in nested view model?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, caliburn.micro

I cannot decipher what all I need for monitoring events in my nested view model (don't think it's relevant but I need to control focus within nested viewModel based on which fields have been filled out). Everything works when it's not nested but as soon as I try to break it out, nothing works.

I have tried to piece the following together but am still struggling. Is there an unbelievably thorough tutorial for dummies out there?

[This one doesn't compile. Out dated?](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/776025/MVVM-Event-Routing-to-the-Child-ViewModel)

https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/issues/213

[Caliburn.Micro nested ViewModels best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25649851/caliburn-micro-nested-viewmodels-best-practice)

I have a parent view model here:

```
public EndUserUnloadViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
        {
            this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
            this.eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
            UnloaderRotaryVm = new UnloaderRotaryViewModel(eventAggregator);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => UnloaderRotaryVm);
        }
```

View:

```
  <DockPanel >

        <nsVi:UnloaderRotaryView DataContext="{Binding UnloaderRotaryVm, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <!--<ContentControl Content="{Binding UnloaderRotaryVm}" />-->
        <!--cal:View.Model="{Binding UnloaderRotaryVm}"-->
    </DockPanel>
```

then, this in the child

```
    public UnloaderRotaryViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator) 
    {
        this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        this.eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
    }
```

then, this in the IOC

```
public static IContainer GetContainer()
        {
            var container = new Container(x =>
            {
               ...
                x.For<IEventAggregator>().Use<EventAggregator>().Singleton();
         ...}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! There was a disjoint between the ViewModel and View folder structure. Hadn't realized that was important for determining the bindings.

https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=View/ViewModel%20Naming%20Conventions

Comment: please realize that the docs on codeplex are way out of date... they are no long maintained, reference http://caliburnmicro.com or  http://github.com/caliburn-micro/caliburn.micro

Answer (score 0):

Can u explain the bigger picture? What are u trying to create?  "unbelievably thorough tutorial for dummies out there?" - for what?  i.e - "C for Dummies" , "Painting for Dummies"?

Comment: Please put questions like these in a comment on the original question, not an answer.  I realize you don't yet have enough rep to comment on other's questions yet, and your questions are quite valid, but they don't belong as an answer.

Comment: I just need to bind to a viewModel nested inside of a main viewModel. I cannot get for example the button clicks to respond to the event they should be bound to.