# Contained ViewModel Events in Caliburn Micro Not Firing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have an ExplorerWindow V/VM UserControl containing another FileSystemTree V/VM UserControl.

Neither of these controls is contained in the Screens collections maintained by the MainVM because the ExplorerWindowView gets shown as a modal popup.

Events are firing on the ExplorerWindowView; but, it is not clear how or why Attached Events are not firing on the contained FileSystemView.

ExplorerWindowView

```
<UserControl x:Class="KTronInd.Wpf.ControlLibrary.FileExplorer.Views.ExplorerWindowView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:view="clr-namespace:KTronInd.Wpf.ControlLibrary.FileExplorer.Views"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         x:Name="Explorer"
         xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
         cal:Message.Attach="[Event Loaded]=[Action ExplorerLoaded($eventArgs)]"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300"
         d:DesignWidth="500">


<Grid x:Name="OuterGrid" 
      Width="800" 
      Height="400">

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition  />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="5" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--Display the DirectoryTree on the left side of the grid DataContext="{Binding Explorer, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" -->
    <view:FileSystemTreeView Grid.Column="0"
                             DataContext="{Binding FileTreeVM}"
                             Grid.Row="0"  
                             Visibility="Visible"/>

    <!-- pane splitter-->
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="0" 
                  Grid.Row="0" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                  Width="3" 
                  Background="Gray" 
                  Visibility="Visible" />

    <!--Display the File and Directory Selector on the right side of the grid DataContext="{Binding Explorer, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" -->
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" >
        <view:DirectoryViewerView />
    </ScrollViewer>

</Grid>
```

...and the ExplorerWindowViewModel

```
[Export( typeof( IScreen ) ), PartCreationPolicy( CreationPolicy.NonShared )]
public class ExplorerWindowViewModel : Screen, IHandle<ModelEvent>
{
[ImportingConstructor]
public ExplorerWindowViewModel( IEventAggregator events )
{
    m_Events = events;
    FileTreeVM = new FileSystemTreeViewModel( this , m_Events );
    //FileTreeVM.ConductWith( this ); 
.
.
}
.
.
public FileSystemTreeViewModel FileTreeVM
    {
        get
        {
            return _fileTreeVM;
        }
        set
        {
            _fileTreeVM = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange( () => FileTreeVM );
        }
    }   
}
```

Here's the FileSystemTreeView

```
UserControl x:Class="KTronInd.Wpf.ControlLibrary.FileExplorer.Views.FileSystemTreeView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:KTronInd.Wpf.ControlLibrary.FileExplorer.ViewModels"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" >

<UserControl.Resources>

    <vm:GetFileSysemInformationConverter x:Key="getFileSysemInformationConverter"/>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType = "{ x:Type vm:DirInfo }" 
                              ItemsSource = "{ Binding Converter={ StaticResource getFileSysemInformationConverter } }" >

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

            <Image Width="20" 
                   Height="20" 
                   Stretch="Fill" 
                   x:Name="img" />

            <TextBlock Text="{ Binding Name }" 
                       Margin="5,0,0,0" />

        </StackPanel>

        <!-- The HDT triggers bind the directory to an image representing the object type. -->
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
            <!-- My Computer -->
            <DataTrigger Binding="{ Binding Path = DirType }" 
                         Value="0">

                <Setter Property="Image.Source" 
                        TargetName="img" 
                        Value="..\Images\MyComputer.jpg" />

            </DataTrigger>

            <!-- A disk drive -->
            <DataTrigger Binding="{ Binding Path = DirType }" 
                         Value="1">

                <Setter Property="Image.Source" 
                        TargetName="img" 
                        Value="..\images\diskdrive.png" />

            </DataTrigger>

            <!-- A folder -->
            <DataTrigger Binding="{ Binding Path = DirType }" 
                         Value="2">

                <Setter Property="Image.Source" 
                        TargetName="img"
                        Value="..\images\folder.png" />

            </DataTrigger>

        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>

    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <!-- TreeViewItem property setters -->
    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </Style>

</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid Background="Beige" >

    <TreeView x:Name="DirectoryTree"  
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path = FileTreeVM.SystemDirectorySource}"
              cal:Message.Attach="[Event Loaded]=[Action FSTViewLoaded($eventArgs)]"
              BorderThickness="0"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
              Width="300" >

    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

And lastly, the FileSystemTreeViewModel

```
[Export( typeof( IScreen ) ), PartCreationPolicy( CreationPolicy.NonShared )]
public class FileSystemTreeViewModel : Screen , IHandle<ModelEvent>
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public FileSystemTreeViewModel( ExplorerWindowViewModel evm , IEventAggregator events )
    {
        m_Events = events;
        InitVM( evm );
    }    
}
```

How can I get events to fire in either: the contained FileSystemTreeView in the ExplorerWindowView or the TreeView control inside of the FileSystemTreeView?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Used Galasoft MVVMlight. No such issues regarding events located in other views, contained or not.

Answer (score 0):

Hi hyland Computer Systems, did you checked if your viewmodel is the actual one? I already had a problem in similar case, where I also declared my vm in view as datacontext (or Ressource, have no clue anymore) and there came no reaction in view while i raised a notifypropetychanged or -changing event. The matter was, that i feeded the "wrong" vm. I had one vm, which was created by view and another one per injection. The injected one was that one, which i feeded. So i simply overwritten my datacontext of my view again, and here we go-> all worked properly.

Comment: Hi, Alexander:  I actually got the one from the Screens collection injected by the DI and used it to create the the dialog. Still same results. Thank you for responding.

Answer (score 0):

`cal:Message.Attach="[Event Loaded]=[Action FSTViewLoaded($eventArgs)]"` do you have this action actually defined?

**Edit:**
clarifying defined.. Do you have a method with that name located in your viewmodel that takes `EventArgs` as the parameter to the method?

Do you have binding errors in the output of the app as it runs?  What the events you are expecting to fire? I would bet and I am not a betting type normally but I would suspect binding errors secondly I would also suspect a limitation of CM you might be hitting associated with the visual tree

Comment: I don't see binding errors in the output window; and, yes, i have moved that event-code-snippet into the FileSystemViewModel both with and without params. Thanks for responding.

Comment: When you say eventing, which events are you expecting?

Comment: Any event, but Loaded would work fine as it would be the first one to execute without any mouse-clicks, etc. This solution might work; but, it is very complicated:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25649851/caliburn-micro-nested-viewmodels-best-practice.  When using MVVMLight I don't have any of these issues.

Comment: right cause MVVMLight isn't CM, CM is ViewModel First, MVVMLight is ViewFirst development.

Comment: So now the suggestion instead of trying to "make the user control work" as the eventing control try attaching that to the actual DirectoryView, wire up the loaded event if necessary with the appropriate viewmodel method and see if that works.  Only other alternative is to do a DP